# how to put a backquote in a backquoted string?

Tags: go

is it possible to print back quotes in Go using back quotes : something like this:

````
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(```) // for example I can do it with double quotes "\""
}
````

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // back ` quote
    fmt.Println((`back ` + "`" + ` quote`))
}
```

> Raw string literals are character
>   sequences between back quotes ``.
>   Within the quotes, any character is
>   legal except back quote. The value of
>   a raw string literal is the string
>   composed of the uninterpreted
>   characters between the quotes; in
>   particular, backslashes have no
>   special meaning and the string may
>   span multiple lines. [String
>   literals](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#String_literals)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with single quotes:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   fmt.Printf("%c\n", '`')
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Printf

Comment: I found this the most idiomatic; adapting it to the answer the question, it would be `fmt.Printf(\`back %c quote\`, '\`')` (see https://go.dev/play/p/pzvfPcz4pm2).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR

```golang
fmt.Println("\x60")
```

\x: Hex <sup>see [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing)</sup>

60<sub>16</sub>
96<sub>10</sub>
140<sub>8</sub> matches the character [`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) <sup>[grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)</sup>

---

[image: Go Playground]