# Go lang differentiate "\n" and line break

Tags: go, split

I am trying read certain string output generated by linux command by the following code:

```
out, err := exec.Command("sh", "-c", cmd).Output()
```

The above out is of `[]byte` type, how can I differentiate the "\n" character contained in line content with the real line break? I tried

```
strings.Split(output, "\n")
```

and

```
bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(output))
```

but they both split the whole string buffer whenever seeing a "\n" character.

OK, to clarify, an "unreal" break is a "\n" character contained in a string as follows, 

`Print first result: "123;\n234;\n"
Print second result: "456;\n"`

The whole output is one big multi-line string, it may also contain some other quoted strings, and I am processing the whole string output in my go program, but I can't control the command output and add a back slash before the "\n" character.

Further clarify: I meant to process byte sequence which contains string of strings, and want to preserve the "`\n`" contained in the inner string and use the the outer layer "`\n`" to break lines. So for the following byte sequence:

```
First line: "test1"
Second line: "123;\n234;\n345;"
Third line: "456;\n567;"
Fourth line: "test4"
```

I want to get 3 lines when processing the whole sequence, instead of getting 7 total lines. It's a old project, but I remember I can use Python to directly get 3 lines using syntax like "`for line in f`", and print the content of second inner string instead of rendering it.

Comment: What is a "real line break"? When is a "\n" an "unreal" line break?

Comment: Depending on the operating system (and/or file format) a line break is either `\n`, or it's `\r\n`, or it's `\r`. There is nothing to "differentiate"; that byte (or byte pair in the case of `\r\n`) *is* the line break. If instead you happen to mean the "\" character followed by "n", you could write that in Go as `"\\n"` or a backquoted literal string (which I can't figure out how to show properly in SO's markdown).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no distinction between a "real" and an "unreal" line break.

If you're using a Unix-like system, the end of a line in a text file is denoted by the LF or `'\n'` character. You cannot have a `'\n'` character in the middle of a line.

A string in memory can contain as many `'\n'` characters as you like. The string `"foo\nbar\n"`, when written to a text file, will create two lines, `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

There is no effective difference between

```
fmt.Println("foo")
fmt.Println("bar")
```

and

```
fmt.Printf("foo\nbar\n")
```

Both print the same sequence of 2 lines, as does this:

```
fmt.Println("foo\nbar")
```

Answer (score 34):

It's possible that your "\n" is actually the escaped version of a line break character. You can replace these with real line breaks by searching for the escaped version and replacing with the non escaped version:

`` strings.Replace(sourceStr, `\n`, "\n", -1) ``

Since string literals inside backticks can be written over multiple lines, Go escapes any line break characters it sees.

Comment: I wanted something I could use to convert all EOL occurrences to `<br>` to format messages for submission to Microsoft Teams (via webhook request). Your answer helped me solve the issue.

In case it is helpful, a modified/working function from a project I use is provided via Go Playground link below. I can't speak to its correctness as I've not fully tested it yet.

https://play.golang.org/p/LQU5rO1I7Bw

Answer (score 2):

The `encoding/csv` package might suit your needs:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/csv"
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

const s = `First line: "test1"
Second line: "123;
234;
345;"
Third line: "456;
567;"
Fourth line: "test4"
`

func main() {
   r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(s))
   r.Comma = ':'
   r.TrimLeadingSpace = true
   a, e := r.ReadAll()
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   fmt.Printf("%q\n", a)
}
```

Result:

```
[
   ["First line" "test1"]
   ["Second line" "123;\n234;\n345;"]
   ["Third line" "456;\n567;"]
   ["Fourth line" "test4"]
]
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv

Answer (score 0):

```
strings.Trim(string, "\f\t\r\n ")
```

Comment: I don't think this helps `get 3 lines when processing the whole sequence, instead of getting 7 total lines`.