# Capturing the output of exec.Command("find", "./helloworld/workspace", "-name", "*.java").Output()

Tags: go

I'm trying to find the path of the helloworld.java file so that I can pass it down to a compiler function.

What I have:

I'm expecting this to return the path, of type []byte and then stringify it, of the only helloworld.java file in this directory and then pass it down to Java() function.

```golang
filePath, _ := exec.Command("find", "./helloworld/workspace", "-name", "*.java").Output()
                    
Java(string(filePath))
```

The Problem is that `cmd := exec.Command("javac", filePath)` in my java() function is not recognizing the file path therefore not compiling it.
But if I hardcode the path that I get from exec.Command("find) like this:
This works fine

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("javac", "./helloworld/workspace/src/main/java/com/coveros/demo/helloworld/HelloWorld.java")
err := cmd.Run()
```

But this does not work:

What am I missing, How do I fix this?

```golang
func Java(filePath string) {
    fmt.Println("compiler start")
    cmd := exec.Command("javac", filePath)
    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
        fmt.Println("compiler End")
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `string(filePath)` ?

Comment: @Christian the output is the path of the java file: ./helloworld/workspace/src/main/java/com/coveros/demo/helloworld/HelloWorld.java

Comment: But what is the actual output of this: `fmt.Println(string(filePath))` Does this show the correct path to the file?

Comment: yes, if i run  `fmt.Println(string(filePath)) `  it show this that path I mentioned above. Thats why it's weird to me that is not working if it clearly returning what i need. Not sure if I'm missing something

Comment: Are you sure that the current working directory is the same in both cases? (i.e. that your program did not change directory in the meantime?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the result from `find` is returning multiple possible paths which are separated by a newline `"\n"`. The newline will be "hidden" if it is printed to the command line. You can try this `fmt.Println(stringPath + "hello, am I on a new line?")` to show the `stringPath` has a new line in it.

See the below which uses a similar version of find looking for json files, then splits the string by newlines and then loops through these paths. If the path is blank (which it can be) it skips over it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    filePath, err := exec.Command("find", ".", "-name", "*.json").Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stringPath := string(filePath)
    paths := strings.Split(stringPath, "\n")

    CatFile(paths)
}

func CatFile(filePaths []string) {
    for _, path := range filePaths {
        if len(path) == 0 {
            continue
        }
            output, err := exec.Command("cat", path).Output()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error!")
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(output))
    }
}
```

See this related question, which discusses this: [Go lang differentiate "\n" and line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042989/go-lang-differentiate-n-and-line-break)

Comment: Yup, that's what it was. Thank you!