# Long queries in golang

Tags: go

This is a question based on absolute no knowledge of golang and the aim is to find if there is a way to make long queries readable.

My attempt is to put the sql text in a variable and then execute the variable.

Pseudocode (no real code):

```
var query = 
SELECT * FROM foo
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM bar
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM other
...

db.prepare (var query)
db.query (var query)
```

This is maybe a dumb question, but I have searched and found no clue how to make long queries more "readable" in go. Most examples are based on "hello world" level. In the real world queries can be quite long.

TIA,

Comment: You could use a [multiline string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933460/how-do-you-write-multiline-strings-in-go)?

Comment: You mean to declare a variable as multiline string?

Comment: yeah, declare the query as a multiline string literal.

Comment: Thank you! First step to understand. Any example?

Comment: I posted an answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can declare the query as a multiline string literal.

```
query := `
  SELECT * FROM foo
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM bar
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM other`
```

And use it with [DB.Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query).

```
rows, err := db.Query(query)
```

There are many different [drivers](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLDrivers) for many different sql databases you can use. They all would give you a [DB](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB) object to work with. So you can use [DB.Prepare](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare), DB.Query appropriately. Check docs of [database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql) package for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods for this

**1. Using backquote:**
Use **(backquote\backtick)** which is with symbol **`** in keyboard.
So that your query will look like

```
query := `INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
          VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');`
```

**2. Using string concatenation:**
 Use string concatenation characters between lines So that your query will look like

```
query :="INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)"+
        "VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');"
```

I prefer the 1st one :)