# How to format a multiline string literal

Tags: go

I am trying to break a string literal into multiple lines to meet my linter's expectations of short lines. Following is the code right now, it passes the linter check:

```
return nil,
    "",
    errors.Errorf(
            `nil cursor returned when querying for transactions for block hash %s, 
page token %s and limit %d`,
            blockHash,
            pageToken,
            limit,
    )
```

I don't like the formatting of the string literal. It feels aesthetically wrong ;). Is there a better way to format this? Thanks!

Comment: Aside from the opinionated nature of the question, this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7933460/13860

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you write multiline strings in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933460/how-do-you-write-multiline-strings-in-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string concatenation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_concatenation) to construct the string from shorter lines:

```
errors.Errorf(
        `nil cursor returned when querying for transactions` +
        ` for block hash %s, page token %s and limit %d`,
        blockHash,
        pageToken,
        limit,
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string addition:

```
errors.Errorf(`nil cursor returned when querying for `+
`transactions for block hash %s, page token %s and limit %d`,
            blockHash,
            pageToken,
            limit,
    )
```