# Issue with creating a byte object

Tags: go

I am trying to initialize a JSON object as a byte in go lang. Here, I am attaching two exmples

```
var countryRegionData = []byte(`{"name": "srinivas"}`)

var countryRegionData = []byte(`{"name": "srini`vas"}`)
```

In the first initilization there is no issue, all working as expected.

In the second initialization if you see there is ` between i and v. I have some requirement like this. How to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to put a backquote in a backquoted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423951/how-to-put-a-backquote-in-a-backquoted-string)

Answer (score 0):

A backtick cannot appear in a raw string literal. You can write something like this:

```
var countryRegionData = []byte("{\"name\": \"srini`vas\"}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use escaping in a raw string literal. Either you have to use double-quoted string:

```
"{\"name\": \"srini'vas\"}"
```

Or do something like:

```
`{"name": "srini`+"`"+"vas"}`
```